# ¿tengo algun error en mi codigo o es un problema de la api?

Tags: api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el de la izquierda es la que me proporciona la api y funciona, el de la derecha es el que yo hice pero al apretar enviar no me llega nada a mi correo

¿HICE ALGO MAL?

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error en la consola

"api.js:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
```

Comment: Mira las rutas, estás apuntando a un lugar inexistente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola. Los errores 404 hacen referencia a recursos no encontrados, sea porque la ruta de dicho recurso está mal, o porque no existe en absoluto. Debes indentificar cuál es el recurso que no está encontrado y revisar la ruta del mismo, verificando que está en esa ubicación o corrigiendo la ruta si está mal escrita. En la consola podrás ver con facilidad cuál es el recurso no encontrando. En cuanto a la pregunta, debes poner el código como texto, no como imagen. Y no hay que poner todo el código, sólo aquello relativo al problema que presentas.

Answer (score 0):

Según por lo que veo, tienes una aplicación que esta ejecutando Node js, pero se supone que lo de la izquierda se ejecuta por que estas enviando desde el lado del servidor, pero lo de la derecha esta ejecutándose desde el lado del cliente, asi que tu import Resend, siemplemente no se reconoce, lo que tienes que hacer es pasar los datos de tu formulario hacia el lado del servidor, ahí recién va a funcionar.

Comment: Gracias,como puedo buscar informacion sobre eso para hacerlo?